# Can't write English in xterm terminal

Tags: cygwin, x11, xterm

My keyboard has two languages, English and other. But in xterm I can write only in other language, and I can't replace the language in any way (alt-lshift, the regular way, or in the gui). With shift key I can write upper case (with caps lock it doesn’t work).

The Cygwin guides on the internet referrals me to xkb layout files, that doesn't existing in my computer at all.

I open the xterm from the icon of Xwin.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is an XTerm running in the Cygwin X server, the X server is doing all the keyboard input translation, independently from the keyboard translation Windows does for other programs (the X server reads the raw keyboard input from the device). So you have to use the X11 methods of changing keyboard layouts. Into your `.xinitrc` or `.xprofile` (I can't remember which one Cygwin uses) put the following command

```
setxkbmap us
```

To load the US keyboard layout. You can type it also from your xterm when you need it. Read the manpage of `setxbmap` for details.

Comment: Need to write it in .bashrc (in home directory)

Comment: @yoni: Putting it into `.bashrc` will call it everytime a bash shell is spawned. This is likely not what you want. Yes it works, but it also can seriously mess up things. You definitely want this in some one-time X startup script.